# If deep link and appInvite both are implemented how will a normal URL work (non-invite URL)?

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links, google-app-invites, deeplink, fbsdkappinvitecontent

I have implemented both AppInvite as well as normal DeepLinks like
added hosts : www.abc.com as well as www.abc.com and pathPrefix as /referrals .
i want to know 
if app isn't installed and we click on the Dynamic link will AppInvite.getInvitation() get called?
if App is installed will the pendingIntent get called or the AppInvite?
how does this work?